# Removing ability to register a different person who is a non-member

Tags: civievent, civimember

I've seen a few references to this problem here and in the old forums, but not a real solution without hacking/overriding.

We have a "Members only" event. But at the very top, a link is provided that allows for a member to register a non-member:

Welcome Rob Brandt. (Not Rob Brandt, or want to register a different person?)

How to prevent this?

Comment: Hi @rob - you don't have any other option - other than override/hacking

Answer (score 1):

We used CSS to hide that message.  Users won't click a link or take an action they don't know they can do!  haha It's stupid simple but it works and we haven't had a problem since.

Here's the CSS we used:

```
/* Prevent people from enroling / contributing for someone else */
.crm-not-you-message {
    display: none;
}
```